# Windows8 OEM Version redownload/reinstall after format

Tags: windows-8, installation, product-key

I bought a Lenovo ideapad y500 with windows 8 pre-installed.

My plan was to format the HDD, install win7 and a fresh win8 with no pre-installed apps etc...

I am now running windows 7 but I can not find a windows 8 ISO to download and I noticed that my laptop is missing a product-key sticker at the bottom.

Since the disk is already reformatted I can not use a product-key registry reader to recover the old windows 8 key.

In short words:

- windows 8 OEM bought.
- HDD and SSD are formatted
- windows7 is running (product-key of my old laptop)
- windows8 ISO and product key is missing

How do I find what my win 8 key is and where can I get a windows 8 ISO ?

Comment: Have you contacted the vendor who sold you the laptop? Did you buy directly from Lenovo? Their support should be able to help you.

Comment: You have to order a Windows 8 installation disc from Lenovo to install Windows 8

Comment: @pratnala: No, the ones available from Microsoft should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ghacks.net/2012/11/10/how-to-re-download-the-windows-8-iso/

Quick internet search brings up an article on how to download the ISO.

The Lack of a product key is more troublesome. Your license key is burned to the BIOS. You'll need customer support to help you get windows 8 installed. Fair warning, it may be a pain in the ass to complete.

http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8/Buyer-Beware-Don-t-format-your-windows-8-disk/td-p/922487

Hope this helps

Comment: i know this article, i can't get the product-key with one of these programs. they all show my windows 7 key.
i tried to submit a support ticket to lenovo but it seems that this kind of support is only for tp-user.

good old times ... i miss them

Comment: Read posts 21, 21, 24, 25 of that thread and you'll see how wrong you are.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 8 install disks all check for keys stored in the EFI (PCs preinstalled with Windows 8 no longer use BIOS as their native boot procedure, although most have legacy BIOS emulation ability), and if one is found you will not be prompted for a key.

This requires no additional effort on your part, provided that the edition you're installing matches the license bundled with the EFI.

(Note: If you want to install a different edition, say Professional or Server, you still won't be prompted for a key, and the install will fail because the key it found doesn't match.  In that case, the easiest thing to do is install from a USB pendrive that has an extra file containing the correct key for the edition you're installing.  That file takes precedence over keys found in the firmware.)

This should help you get the install image you need:

- http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/29322-The-Official-Windows-8-Repository

And here's another explanation of the embedded serial:

- http://rog.asus.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-27777.html

Answer (score -2):

[Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) can recover your windows license key.

Comment: This is almost comment length, could you expand on it a little?